# How to get array data from dynamic tabs and delete current tabs by jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I'm creating dynamic tabs. I'm currently facing two problems:

1. When I click on the span **x** to delete current tab, it deletes all my tabs.
2. When I getting the array data, it always gets the first tab data only.

Can anyone help me with this? I've tried many ways but I still cannot get my desired result. Here is my fiddle [Dynamic Tabs](https://jsfiddle.net/trepksd0/1/).

Currently my array result looks like this for the 2nd problem when there is two tabs, '2023' and '2025':

```
[{
  February: "1",
  January: "1",
  Year: "2023"
}, {
  February: "1",
  January: "1",
  Year: "2023"
}]
```

My expected result would be:

```
[{
  February: "1",
  January: "1",
  Year: "2023"
}, {
  February: "1",
  January: "1",
  Year: "2025"
}]
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  addTab();
});

$('#add_tab').click(function() {
  addTab()
});

//delete current tab
$(".nav-tabs").on("click", "span", function() {
  var anchor = $(this).siblings('a');
  console.log(anchor)
  $(anchor.attr('href')).remove();
  $(this).parent().remove();
  $(".nav-tabs").children('a').first().click();
});

function addTab() {
  var nextTab = $(".nav-tabs").children().length;
  var date = new Date().getFullYear() + nextTab;

  // create the tab
  $('<a class="nav-link" href="#tab-' + date + '" data-toggle="tab">' + date + '</a><span> x </span>').appendTo('#tabs');

  // create the tab content
  var html = "";
  html += '<div class="tab-pane monthSettings" id="tab-' + date + '">';
  html += '<label><b>Year: </b></label>';
  html += '<input class="txtYear" type="text" value="' + date + '">';
  html += '<label><b>January: </b></label>';
  html += '<input class="txtJanuary" type="number" value="1">';
  html += '<label><b>February: </b></label>';
  html += '<input class="txtFebruary" type="number" value="1">';
  html += '</div>';

  //append to tab-content
  var test = $(html).appendTo('.tab-content');

  // make the new tab active
  $('#tabs a:last').tab('show');
}

//get array
$(document).on('click', '#btnGetArray', function(e) {
  var array = []
  $(".monthSettings").each(function() {
    let detail = {
      Year: $(".txtYear").val() || 0,
      January: $(".txtJanuary").val() || 0,
      February: $(".txtFebruary").val() || 0,
    }
    array.push(detail)
    console.log(array)
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.nav-tabs>a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.nav-tabs>a>span {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 8px;
  color: red;
}

.nav-tabs>a>span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css">

<div class="bg-gray-300 nav-bg">
  <nav class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
    <a href="#" class="add-contact" id="add_tab">+ Add Year</a>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="card-body tab-content"></div>

<button id="btnGetArray">GetData</button>
```

Comment: I appreciate the working code snippet, but the question is not clear enough. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I tried to run your example locally and I'm unable to do it. The browser conosle shows me `$(...).tab() is not function`. How can I make it work?

Comment: @JuanMarco The question is for me clear. I can repoduce it when I run the fiddle example. But locally not :-|

Comment: @Reporter Have you include the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js? Or you can directly edit on the fiddle.

Comment: @Esther It was not obvious jsfiddle that uses bootstrap.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because your selectors for retrieving the `.txtYear`, `.txtJanuary` and `.txtFebruary` will only look at the value of the *first* element in the collection, no matter how many it finds.

To correct this you can use `find()` from the parent element, which you can reference from the `each()` loop, to retrieve the child elements in that iteration.

Taking this a step further, you can simplify the logic by using `map()` instead of `each()` to build your array, but the use of `find()` remains the same.

In addition, there's some other improvements which can be made to the code, such as ensuring all event handlers are within `document.ready` and using template literals to make the HTML string concatenation easier to read.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#add_tab').on('click', addTab);

  addTab();

  $(".nav-tabs").on("click", "span", function() {
    var anchor = $(this).siblings('a');
    console.log(anchor)
    $(anchor.attr('href')).remove();
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $(".nav-tabs").children('a').first().click();
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#btnGetArray', e => {
    var array = $(".monthSettings").map((i, container) => ({
      Year: $(container).find('.txtYear').val() || 0,
      January: $(container).find('.txtJanuary').val() || 0,
      February: $(container).find('.txtFebruary').val() || 0,
    })).get();
    
    console.log(array);
  });
});

function addTab() {
  var nextTab = $(".nav-tabs").children().length;
  var date = new Date().getFullYear() + nextTab;

  $(`<a class="nav-link" href="#tab-${date}" data-toggle="tab">${date}</a><span> x </span>`).appendTo('#tabs');

  var html = `
    <div class="tab-pane monthSettings" id="tab-${date}">
      <label><b>Year: </b></label>
      <input class="txtYear" type="text" value="${date}" />
      <label><b>January: </b></label>
      <input class="txtJanuary" type="number" value="1" />
      <label><b>February: </b></label>
      <input class="txtFebruary" type="number" value="1" />
    </div>`
  var test = $(html).appendTo('.tab-content');

  // make the new tab active
  $('#tabs a:last').tab('show');
}
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.nav-tabs>a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.nav-tabs>a>span {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 8px;
  color: red;
}

.nav-tabs>a>span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css">

<div class="bg-gray-300 nav-bg">
  <nav class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
    <a href="#" class="add-contact" id="add_tab">+ Add Year</a>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="card-body tab-content"></div>

<button id="btnGetArray">GetData</button>
```

Comment: thanks, solve my 2nd problem. How about the delete tab?? do u have any idea?

Comment: There's a few issues there, such as using `siblings('a')` which will return multiple elements not just the neighbouring element,  and also `$(this).parent().remove();` which will remove the entire nav-tabs container. In addition calling `click()` on the first element may cause issues too. I'd suggest starting a new question to cover that topic, though.